# Convert dynamic string to JSON using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string, casting

I am using API that its response contains dynamic array of strings as the following:

```
var arr = ["Request.name","Request.name.first","Request.name.first.last"]; //response 3
```

so i want to convert it dynamically to array of JSON objects like this:

```
var arrayOfObjects = [ 
               { 
                 "Request": {
                 "name":val 
                 }
               } //converted from arr[0]
            ,{ 
                 "Request": {
                  "name":{
                   "first":val
                  }
                 }
              } //converted from arr[1] 
            ,{ 
                 "Request": {
                  "name":{
                   "first":{
                     "last":val
                   }
                  }
                 }
               } //converted from arr[2] 
        ];
```

and so on...

is this possible?

Comment: Probably, have you made any attempt yourself yet? Post the code you've tried if you want debugging help

Comment: what is the value of `val`?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: @LeonidPyrlia constant value for all of the objects. it may be 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function that converts a dot-separated string into a respective deeply nested object, then map your input array of strings with it. My solution is iterative, though I think it can be done recursively as well.

```
var arr = ["Request.name","Request.name.first","Request.name.first.last"];

function createObjFromStr(str) {

    return str.split('.').reduceRight((all, key, i, arr) => {

        if (i === arr.length - 1) {
            all = {[key]: 0};
        } else {
            all[key] = Object.assign({}, all);
            Object.keys(all).forEach(k => {
                if (k !== key) delete all[k];
            });
        }

        return all;

    }, {});

}

const arrayOfObjects = arr.map(createObjFromStr);

console.log(arrayOfObjects);
```